# Why does it seem like owls are more seen than any other animal

Tags: futurama

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are the owls in Futurama a backwards reference to Blade Runner and Do Androids Dream of Electric Sheep?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18186/are-the-owls-in-futurama-a-backwards-reference-to-blade-runner-and-do-androids-d)

Why does it seem like owls are seen more often than any other animal? Especially in the older seasons owls were always in the background or briefly seen doing something abstract. Maybe someone on the staff just liked drawing them

Answer (score 5):

In the commentary for the 3rd season episode *Parasites Lost*, they mention this.  In the future, owls have replaced rats as the common vermin.  However due to the animators screwing up sometimes, rats were being included in the background of some scenes, so they're still around too.